# How to show current object inside template used with class based FormView

Tags: python, django, formview

Having this urls.py snippet:

```
url(r'^storageitem/(?P<pk>[\w]+)/addtransaction/$', login_required(
    StorageItemTransactionAddView.as_view()), 
    name='storage_item_transaction'),
```

I'm wondering what is the correct way to make the object beihind pk available inside a template to show it e.g. with

```
<h1>{{ object.name }}</h1>
```

I tried to configure a query set

```
...
queryset = StorageItem.objects.get
    pk=get_from_kwargs()['object'])

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(ItemCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({
        'object' : self.kwargs['pk']
    })
    return kwargs
```

but the method is not access able at this point. So I'm wondering how could one do it the correct way? All I need would be something like

```
self.object = StorageItem.objects.get(pk='my pk')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) to pass extra context:

```
...

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ItemCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['storage_item'] = StorageItem.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return context
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do the following:

```
class StorageItemTransactionAddView(View):

    def post(self, request, pk):
        storage_item = StorageItem.objects.get(pk=pk)
        ...
        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'object': storage_item})
```

Now in your template, you can do the following:

```
<h1>{{ object.name }}</h1>
```

Hope it helps